# Motivation of Holographic Exact Renormalisation Equation

Tags: string-theory, renormalization, ads-cft, effective-field-theory, holographic-principle

I've recently been studying exact renormalisation alongside holographic renormalisation, and came across the following paper on the arXiv: https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0001193.

I'm trying to understand the motivation for equation (5) which is as follows:

$$ < \partial_t S_1 + K_1^{ij, lk} \frac{\partial S_1}{\partial \Phi_{ij}} \frac{\partial S_1}{\partial \Phi_{lk}} + K_2^{ij, lk} \frac{\partial^2 S_1}{\partial \Phi_{ij} \partial \Phi_{lk}} + K_3 > = 0, $$

where $S_0$ is some "free" action associated with a 0-d matrix model of the form

$$ -\frac{N}{2} K(t) \mathrm{tr} \Phi^2, $$

and $S_1$ includes some interaction terms of the form

$$ N \sum_{n > 2} \phi_n(t) \mathrm{tr} \Phi^n $$

with a smooth time-dependent cutoff $K(t)$.

I guess (5) is meant to vaguely resemble Polchinski's equation, but I'm failing to see how. The double derivatives seem familiar, but then why is there the partial time derivative term? The paper goes on to 'derive' equation (5), but as far as I can see it relies on knowledge of the form.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.